# ERROR 1822 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I've been working on this sql project about a game rental store.

I've created the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
MEMBERSHIP_ID NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
FNAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
LNAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
TELEFONE NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
BIRTHDAY DATE);
```

AND:

```
CREATE TABLE INVENTORY(
-> GAME_ID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
-> TITLE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
-> PLATAFORM VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
-> EDITION YEAR,
-> GENRE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
-> PUBLISHER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
-> PRICE NUMERIC(4,2) DEFAULT 00.00 NOT NULL);
```

AND:

```
CREATE TABLE RENTAL (
-> RENTAL_NO VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
-> DATE_OUT DATE NOT NULL,
-> DATE_OF_RETURN DATE NOT NULL,
-> MEMBERSHIP_ID NUMERIC(10),
-> GAME_ID VARCHAR(10),
-> INDEX (MEMBERSHIP_ID),
-> CONSTRAINT FK_RENTAL_CUST FOREIGN KEY(MEMBERSHIP_ID) REFERENCES
-> CUSTOMER (MEMBERSHIP_ID),
-> INDEX (GAME_ID),
-> CONSTRAINT FK_RENTAL_INV FOREIGN KEY(GAME_ID) REFERENCES
-> INVENTORY (GAME_ID));
```

Now I need a table for the transaction that will connect the price and I've been getting the error mentioned:

```
CREATE TABLE OPEN_TRANSACTION (
RENTAL_NO VARCHAR (10),
MEMBERSHIP_ID NUMERIC (10),
DATE_OUT DATE NOT NULL,
DATE_OF_RETURN DATE NOT NULL,
GAME_ID VARCHAR (10),
ITEM_PRICE NUMERIC(4,2) DEFAULT 00.00 NOT NULL,
INDEX (RENTAL_NO),
INDEX (MEMBERSHIP_ID),
INDEX (GAME_ID),
INDEX (ITEM_PRICE),
INDEX (DATE_OUT),
INDEX (DATE_OF_RETURN),
CONSTRAINT PK_OPEN_TRANSACTION PRIMARY KEY (RENTAL_NO, GAME_ID, DATE_OUT),
CONSTRAINT FK_OPENTRAN_RENTAL FOREIGN KEY (RENTAL_NO, DATE_OUT, DATE_OF_RETURN) REFERENCES
RENTAL (RENTAL_NO, DATE_OUT, DATE_OF_RETURN),
CONSTRAINT FK_OPENTRAN_CUST FOREIGN KEY (MEMBERSHIP_ID) REFERENCES
CUSTOMER (MEMBERSHIP_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_OPENTRAN_INV FOREIGN KEY (GAME_ID) REFERENCES
INVENTORY (GAME_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_OPENTRAN_INV FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_PRICE) REFERENCES
INVENTORY (PRICE));
```

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key must reference a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY of the parent table.

All columns of the foreign key must match columns in the key it references, and they must be the same data types and in the same order.

In your case, you have columns in OPEN_TRANSACTION: RENTAL_NO, DATE_OUT, DATE_OF_RETURN, and you tried to reference the three columns of the same name in the RENTAL table, but the primary key of the RENTAL table is only the single column RENTAL_NO.

It seems to me that it would work fine for OPEN_TRANSACTION to have a single-column foreign key: RENTAL_NO, referencing RENTAL (RENTAL_NO). That would be a legal foreign key. It can't be ambiguous, because RENTAL_NO is already the primary key of the RENTAL table, therefore there an only be one record in that table for a given RENTAL_NO value.

An alternative would be to create a redundant UNIQUE KEY in the RENTAL table, for the set of three columns. That would allow the three columns of OPEN_TRANSACTION to comprise a foreign key, but it doesn't seem like good relational database design.

Why do you have columns DATE_OUT and DATE_OF_RETURN in the OPEN_TRANSACTIONS table? If those columns must always have the same values as they have in the RENTAL table, then they are stored redundantly. If those columns can change their value in the OPEN_TRANSACTIONS table, then they shouldn't be used as a foreign key.

Besides that foreign key, you also have another problem:

The foreign key in OPEN_TRANSACTIONS on ITEM_PRICE references the INVENTORY.PRICE column, which is not a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY. It's not clear why you would put a foreign key on this column, or why you would store the price in the OPEN_TRANSACTIONS table, since it's already in the INVENTORY table.

The best reason I can come up with is that you want to record the price at the time a purchase was made, so you have a record of what was paid. Prices go up and down, and to make a ledger you'd need to save what price it was on the date of each purchase. But then you wouldn't use a foreign key on that price to reference the price in the inventory, because the whole point of copying the price into the other table is that the values should be allowed to be different.

Comment: Thank you. I am struggling with the basic concepts yet and I clearly was duplicating information without any need.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error message is, that you have foreign key constraints that reference a tuple of columns in another table where the columns in that tuple aren't (uniquely) indexed (in the same order). Namely that are the constraints `FK_OPENTRAN_RENTAL` and `FK_OPENTRAN_INV`.

But you seem to have misunderstood what foreign keys are for anyway. Foreign keys reference rows in other tables, and do not check if any odd column values are the same in two tables. In fact you should leave the values in the original table, you can retrieve it from the other table by using the foreign key to identify the right row in the other table and read the information from there. Storing the same piece of information at more than one place even is dangerous as the values in the different place could get different and you no longer know which one is the right one.

So the columns `DATE_OUT` and `DATE_OF_RETURN` don't belong in `OPEN_TRANSACTION`. Just have the `RENTAL_NO` in `OPEN_TRANSACTION`. With it you can find the right row in `RENTAL` and get the values from there. The same applies to `ITEM_PRICE` in `OPEN_TRANSACTION`. You have the `GAME_ID` foreign key, to find the right game and therefore the right price in `INVENTORY`.

Change your `CREATE` statement accordingly. Removing the superfluous columns also removes or alters the foreign key constraints in a way that there is no error anymore.

```
CREATE TABLE OPEN_TRANSACTION (
RENTAL_NO VARCHAR (10),
MEMBERSHIP_ID NUMERIC (10),
GAME_ID VARCHAR (10),
INDEX (RENTAL_NO),
INDEX (MEMBERSHIP_ID),
INDEX (GAME_ID),
CONSTRAINT PK_OPEN_TRANSACTION PRIMARY KEY (RENTAL_NO, MEMBERSHIP_ID, GAME_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_OPENTRAN_RENTAL FOREIGN KEY (RENTAL_NO) REFERENCES
RENTAL (RENTAL_NO),
CONSTRAINT FK_OPENTRAN_CUST FOREIGN KEY (MEMBERSHIP_ID) REFERENCES
CUSTOMER (MEMBERSHIP_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_OPENTRAN_INV FOREIGN KEY (GAME_ID) REFERENCES
INVENTORY (GAME_ID));
```

Comment: That's brilliant, I had a hint I understood the concept wrong, but I couldn't get my head around it by myself, thank you.